# How to create an observable of the difference between two sorted observables?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, observable, reactivex, rx-scala

Let's say I have two observables of sorted doubles. I'd like to get the difference between them as an observable. For instance:

```
           1       2           4        
 left:   ──o───────o───────────o────/
           1    3  4   5
 right:  ──o────o──o───o───/
                   l2          r3   r5
 output: ──────────o───────────o────o─/
```

The imperative implementation for this is simple: Keep a list of the items on the side that you've still not reached and "emit" the items from the other side.

What is the canonical approach to this in the world of RFP? I'm specifically using RxScala.

Comment: Can you provide a marble diagram showing when the values from the sources are emitted and how that leads to the resulting observable?

Comment: @Enigmativity I've added a marble diagram. HTH

Comment: That's a nice marble diagram. How did you make that? I still can't figure out the rule though. Can you explain it please?

Comment: @Enigmativity it's an artisanal, hand-crafted marble diagram, made from only the finest ASCII characters (aka I made it by hand). the simple explanation is that I want the difference between both observables, sorted and as soon as I can understand that it doesn't exist in either of the sides.

Comment: You might need to try again - "is that I want the difference between both observables, sorted and as soon as I can understand that it doesn't exist in either of the sides" - that just doesn't make sense to me at all, sorry.

Comment: @Enigmativity Both sources stream sorted data. I want to know, as soon as it's possible, which elements do not exist on either side. I don't want to wait until the streams are over. It's technically possible to do this and the imperative implementation is simple.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it in rxjava implied that two observables have the same length.

```
    Observable<Integer> obs1 = Observable.just(1, 2, 4, 6);
    Observable<Integer> obs2 = Observable.just(1, 3, 4, 5);

    obs1.zipWith(obs2, (integer, integer2) -> {
        if (!Objects.equals(integer, integer2)) {
            return Observable.just(integer).concatWith(Observable.just(integer2));
        } else {
            return Observable.empty();
        }
    })
      .flatMap(observable -> observable)
      .sorted()
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

**EDIT**

Another approach would be to use a collection

```
    Observable<Integer> obs1 = Observable.just(1, 2, 4);
    Observable<Integer> obs2 = Observable.just(1, 3, 4, 5);


    obs1.mergeWith(obs2)
            .sorted()
            .reduce(new ArrayList<Integer>(), (integers, integer) -> {
                if (integers.contains(integer)) {
                    integers.remove(integer);
                } else {
                    integers.add(integer);
                }
                return integers;
            })
            .flatMapIterable(integers -> integers)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: You're making two assumptions here: 1. That the observables are of the same length (I've updated the question to show they're not), and; 2. That one of the observables can't be far ahead of the other (they advance at the same rate).

Comment: Wouldn't this new approach require blocking until both observables complete?

Comment: @OmervanKloeten no, there's no blocking, all operators are producing non-blocking observables.

Comment: What I meant was the 'sorted' operator waits for all elements to return from both sources before emitting its first result.

Comment: @OmervanKloeten you can remove it and get the same result

Comment: Oh, I see. You're right. However, aren't you accumulating the entire resulting observable in memory (by using reduce) before releasing it, effectively blocking the next step (flatMapIterable)?

Comment: @OmervanKloeten yep, it works like `.distinct()` operator keeping all intermediate results in a memory buffer.

Comment: Yeah, so great answer and thank you for giving and explaining it, but I was looking for a version where results would be released to subscribers as soon as they become available.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is much in RxJava to do that symmetric difference "in real time"... Mainly because your starting assumption (the observables are sorted) cannot be made by generic operators, so few will help you with that.

However, you could try to code a custom operator for that purpose, by taking inspiration from `sequenceEqual`: it internally advances step-by-step between two publishers to perform equality comparison, so that's close to what you want to do.